# How to add text to href after a certain slash

Tags: jquery, text, href

Hi guys I would like to change the following :

```
<a class="page larger" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/page/5/">5</a>
```

to:

```
<a class="page larger" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/home/page/5/">5</a>
```

using jQuery.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var sHref = $("a.larger").attr("href").replace("page", "home/page");
$("a.larger").attr("href", sHref);
```